# C# ASP.NET User control How to handle a div click server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am creating an user control. The user control is a div and I want to add a click event to it.

Edit:

The page that has this control on it has to handle this event.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to define an event on your `UserControl` that allows `Page` that contains the `UserControl` to register and handle the event. For example:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{    
    // Event for page to handle
    public event EventHandler DivClicked;

    protected virtual void OnDivClicked(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DivClicked != null)
            DivClicked(this, e);
    }        

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Page Load Code goes here
    }
}
```

Note:
The next part would be easier if you were using a control that supported postbacks. However, since you want to use a `div`, I'll explain how to force a `div` to do postbacks. I'd like thank [Mathew Nolton](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx) for this solution.

So, in the `Page_Load` method of the `UserControl` you need add an `onClick` attribute to call the ASP.NET's `__doPostback()` javascript function that calls the server back for your `div`. This is what gives a `div` the ability to postback to the server. In addition, to determine which control caused the postback, I supplied the `div`'s `ClientId` along with some symbols to differentiate my postback from other controls. Remember when you define the `div` on the .ascx file it has to have an `id` assigned and set `runat="server"`, to be accessible on the server side.

Ok, now by adding an `onclick` attribute to the `div`, it will postback to the server anytime its clicked. So, when a postback causes `Page_Load` to get called, I check to see if it was the `div` which caused the postback. If so, I raise the `UserControl`'s `DivClicked` event to be handled by the Page.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // Event Definition and Raising methods
    ...

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // @@@@ will denote this is an argument I provided.
       string arg = "@@@@" + divClickableDiv.ClientID;
       // Add postback method to onClick 
       divClickableDiv.Attributes.Add("onClick", 
       Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(divClickableDiv, arg));

       if (IsPostBack)
       {
           // Get event arguments for post back.
           string eventArg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

           // Determine if postback is a custom postback added by me.
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArg) && eventArg.StartsWith("@@@@"))
           {
               // Raise the click event for this UserControl if the div
               // caused the post back.
               if (eventArg == arg) 
                   OnDivClicked(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do it for the `UserControl`, now all you have to do is register for the `DivClicked` event on the page.

Unfortunately, you wont get design time support to register for the event. However, you can still add the code to the .aspx page. On the page where you drop your `UserControl` add an attribute to the `UserControl` called `OnXXX` where XXX is the name event. So, for my example above i would define my `UserControl` on the page would look like this:

```
<uc1:MyUserControl  ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server" OnDivClicked="MyUserControl1_DivClicked" />
```

Now you add your handler code to the `Page`'s codebehind file (assuming your using codebehind) like this:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    // Called whenever div in MyUserControl is clicked.
    protected void WebUserControl1_DivClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle Div click event here.
    }
}
```

That should do it. I hope this post helps you.

Comment: Wow, what a fine explanation! Very interesting stuff! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div runat="server" onserverclick="MyClickHandler">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Is this really true? Conflicts with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309718/onserverclick-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Rocka's answer is close, but not quite right (as in it didn't work for me, and I figured out why).

The code bits for the Rocka's usercontrol are fine:
   // Event for page to handle 
    public event EventHandler DivClicked;

```
protected virtual void OnDivClicked(EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (DivClicked != null) 
        DivClicked(this, e); 
}
```

When consuming the UserControl, the following will not work:

the OnDivClicked is not the event handler, it's a function, so you can't assign it.  let alone, when the function fires, the actual event handler variable is null, so it's not going to execute anything.

The proper way would have been:

This would have assigned MyUserControl1_DivClicked to be the handler for DivClicked.  Sadly, this wasn't actually working, so in the code-behind on the page's Page_Load, put this line instead:

this.MyUserControl1.OnClick += new EventHandler(MyUserControl1);

Also, as a side note, if you make the div be runat="server", then OnClick is exposed as an event that you could have hooked into.  All you would have needed is a passthru property for EventHandler in the user control to the div.

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemTemplate **USE asp:Panel INSTEAD OF div tag** (a panel renders as a div) and set the Visibility property like so:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ImgFeatured" runat="server" CssClass="featured-ribbon"> </asp:Panel>
```

Code behind

```
Panel ImgFeatured = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("ImgFeatured");
ImgFeatured.Visible = true;
```