# 'onserverclick' not working

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm trying to handle a click within a `div` in my code behind:

```
<div id="divSearch" runat="server" class="box" onserverclick="aaa">Search</div>
```

and

```
protected void aaa(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx");
}
```

It's simply not working. Any ideas?

(I know this isn't best practice but I'm just experimenting)

Comment: Is that div what actually gets rendered? If so no it wont work, onserverclick is not a js event

Comment: gets rendered as '<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divSearch" class="box" onserverclick="aaa">'

Comment: @aboh - i don't know asp, maybe the framework has attached an onclick event to the div. When you click, is a request actually made to the server?

Answer (score 0):

No such event "onserverclick" exist on div, you can try using different controls like LinkButton, Button etc...

Comment: why does the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470689/c-asp-net-user-control-how-to-handle-a-div-click-server-side have 4 votes

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with Javascript and __doPostback.

Here's an example: [__doPostBack function](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/)

Comment: Surely it is bad practice to go calling that directly isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I should say this is not really recommended.